# Switch images when buttons pressed, currently need to click twice before anything changes

Tags: reactjs, image, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I have a series of images which I want to function as buttons. Currently I have two transparent divs positioned above an image. The starting image has both "buttons" turned off. When you click on the left div, it switches the image source to one where the left button is turned on, etc.

The problem I am running into is that you need to click any div twice before it registers the press. When you switch buttons, the first two presses turn on and off the previous button, then start turning on and off the current one.

I know that I'm overly complicating it but I can't figure out the logic behind when to set the button as pressed and when to change the image. I have tried moving the jQuery after the setSelectedImage hooks, as well as copying the setSelectedImage conditionals and moving them after the pressButton hooks.

```
function App() {
  const [imageSelected, setSelectedImage] = useState(imagesArray[2])
  const [leftButtonPressed, pressLeftButton] = useState(false)
  const [rightButtonPressed, pressRightButton] = useState(false)

  const switchImage = (num) => {

    if (num === 0 && leftButtonPressed === false) {
      pressLeftButton(true)
    } else if (num === 0 && leftButtonPressed === true) {
      pressLeftButton(false)
    }
    if (num === 1 && rightButtonPressed === false) {
      pressRightButton(true)
    } else if (num === 1 && rightButtonPressed === true) {
      pressRightButton(false)
    }

    if (leftButtonPressed === false && rightButtonPressed === false) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[2])
    } else if (leftButtonPressed === true && rightButtonPressed === false) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[0])
    } else if (leftButtonPressed === true && rightButtonPressed === true) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[1])
    } else if (leftButtonPressed === false && rightButtonPressed === true) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[3])
    }

    $('.main-console').css('background-image', `url("${imageSelected}")`)
  }
  
  return (<>
    <div className="App-background">
      <div className="App-container" style={{height: height, width: width}}>>
        <div className="main-console" style={{height: height, width: width}}>>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          <div className='leftSideButton' style={{height: height, width: width/2, left: 0}} onClick={()=>{switchImage(0)}}></div>
          <div className='rightSideButton' style={{height: height, width: width/2, right: 0}} onClick={()=>{switchImage(1)}}>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tentatively solved this, although I doubt it is the ideal solution. I moved the image selection code inside of useEffect, and put the state variables in the dependency array so that the image is updated whenever the variable changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    if (leftButtonPressed === false && rightButtonPressed === false) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[2])
    } else if (leftButtonPressed === true && rightButtonPressed === false) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[0])
    } else if (leftButtonPressed === true && rightButtonPressed === true) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[1])
    } else if (leftButtonPressed === false && rightButtonPressed === true) {
      setSelectedImage(imagesArray[3])
    }
    $('.main-console').css('background-image', `url("${imageSelected}")`)
    return () => {

    }
  }, [imageSelected, leftButtonPressed, rightButtonPressed])
  
  const switchImage = (num) => {

    if (num === 0 && leftButtonPressed === false) {
      pressLeftButton(true)
    } else if (num === 0 && leftButtonPressed === true) {
      pressLeftButton(false)
    }
    if (num === 1 && rightButtonPressed === false) {
      pressRightButton(true)
    } else if (num === 1 && rightButtonPressed === true) {
      pressRightButton(false)
    }
  }
```